# Google COLAB crashes whenever I try to import the ember [dataset] library

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, malware

First I install the EMBER dataset packages to the notebook as specified on their repo, https://github.com/elastic/ember

```
!mv ember ember-master
!cp -r ember-master/* .
!pip install -r requirements.txt
!python setup.py install
```

Colab manages to run this section fine and installs the packages.

However, when I try to import the ember library, it gives an "COLAB Crashed unexpectedly" error and restarts the runtime.

I was able to use the library fine a couple months back, don't know what happened now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue, the problem was the lief library that you use when you import ember. IDK what's wrong with the current version of it.
Anyway the solution was to install an earlier version of lief:

```
pip install lief==0.11.5
```

hope this helps